# MVC 3 Ajax.ActionLink How to get the status code in the onFailure handler?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajax.net

In the action called by an Ajax action link, I need to throw an HttpException based on the current conditions. Depending on those conditions, the HttpException has a different code.

How do I get the status code in the onFailure handler?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I figured out you do not need to throw an HttpException. Instead do:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401);
```

The onFailure handler should look like this:

```
function handleOnFailure(response) {
        alert(response.status);
    }
```

For me the only problem is now how to handle the 401 myself instead of MVC showing the logon page. In case of a 401 the alert is not shown, but with any other statuscode this works.

Comment: @FabioMilheiro, when you throw an HttpException you always get a 500 internal server error.

Comment: OK. I remmeber now I had a similar problem. You are using ActionLink. Use jQuery directly. Here's an answer with an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064261/how-to-return-404-status-in-jquery/2064277#2064277. You should achieve the result you're seeking (use xhr!).

Comment: @FabioMilheiro: I prefer to use MVC helpers only to keep everything consistent, but (when I have some free time..) I'll give it a try by building my own helpers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `AjaxOptions.OnFailure` property to a function like this:

```
<script>
function onFailure(xhr, status) {
    alert(xhr.statusText);
}
</script>
```

See this post: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28583187/MVC-Ajax-BeginForm-how-to-handle-OnSuccess-and-OnFailure-from-Controller.html